# Take array from one form and display contents in labels on another form

Tags: arrays, vb.net, forms, label

I am working on some code that stores a user's answers into an array and compares them with another array with the correct answers in it.  I have already got that part working.  The part I am stuck on is having the user's answers appear in labels on another form( the exam results form )  I create an array for the labels in the other form, then make it equal to the array of user answers, but for some reason they are not displaying on the next form when i click submit.

Code:

```
'Display user answers on the exam result form
    Dim aUserAnswersDisplayed() As String = {frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer1.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer2.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer3.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer4.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer5.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer6.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer7.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer8.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer9.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer10.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer11.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer12.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer13.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer14.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer15.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer16.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer17.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer18.Text,
                                             frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer19.Text, frmExamResults.lblUserAnswer20.Text}

    For intDisplayAnswers = 0 To 19
        aUserAnswersDisplayed(intDisplayAnswers) = aUserAnswers(intDisplayAnswers)
    Next

    frmExamResults.Show()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two form Named `Form1` and `Form2` and you want content from `Form1` displayed on `Form2`. Here is the method you can use

Create a `New()` method on `Form2`

```
Dim _value1 as <DataType>,.......
Public Sub New(ByVal value1 as <DataType>,...........)
    `INITIALIZATION FUNCTION WILL CREATE AUTOMATICALLY`
    _value1 = value1
End Sub
```

Now on `Form1`, call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` method after creating and using `Form2` object. This methods will show you the constructor defined in `Form1` created using `New()` method. Pass the desired values and you will have your values on `Form2`.

```
Dim a as Form1
a.ShowDialog(<Parameters here>)
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor with parameters in FrmExamsResult and pass the array in the object constructor. The other option is to define a property in the form. Once instantiated the object you can set the array in the property.

Another option is to use a singleton class where you store the array. Being singleton can be accessed from both forms.

Greetings